# Injecting special character in website throws error shows sensitive information

Tags: asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

Iam stuck with a problem in protecting sensitive information. I have a legacy mvc application deployed in iis server, during security audit they try to inject special character on my url to reveal sensitive information being exposed. I handled it by redirecting it to the customized page when they provide invalid or special characters on my controller or method name in the url, but unfortunately when they inject characters like '%7f', '*', '!', '~' in the domain or website name i could not handle it. Infact I do not have idea how to handle it. Can someone help me with reference or ideas.

In my web.config file i mentioned

Comment: If you have a (very) limited number of URLs you could try to create rewrite rule(s) that only allow these.